# Java loan calculator

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a loan calculator. I seem to be having issues. I am trying to get an input from the user and validate the input. I know I am doing it wrong the problem is I'm scratching my head wondering how to do it right.
I get a red line on the d = getDouble(sc, prompt); and the i = getInt(sc, prompt); which I understand I don't have that coded correctly. I'm just unsure how to go about fixing it.

I also have to validate the continue statement which I wasn't to sure the best way to go about that and finally the instructor expects the code to be 80 lines or less which I am right about 80 lines. I guess I'm looking for a better way to do this but being new I'm scratching my head and I'm hoping someone can lend a hand.

As always I really appreciate the help.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class LoanCalculator
    {   
        public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max)
        {
          double d = 0.0;
          boolean isValid = false;
          while(isValid == false);
           {
                d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
                if (d <= min)
                   {
                   System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater tha 0.0");
                   }
                   else if (d >= max)
                  {
                     System.out.println("Error number must be less than 1000000.0");
                }
                else 
                    isValid = true;
            }
            return d;       
        }
            public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max)
        {
            int i = 0;
            boolean isvalid = false;
            while(isvalid == false)
             {
                i = getInt(sc, prompt);
                if (i <= min)
                       System.out.println("Error! Number must be more than 0");
                else if (i >= max)
                    System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than 100");
                else 
                    isvalid = true;
            }   
        }
          public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the loan calculator");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String choice = "y";
            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
                System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
                double loanAmount = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter loan amount: ", 0.0, 1000000.0);
                double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 20);
                int years = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);
                int months = years * 12;

                double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate/
                        (1 - 1/Math.pow(1 + interestRate, months));

                NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
                percent.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
                System.out.println("RESULST");
                System.out.println("Loan Amount" + currency.format(loanAmount));
                System.out.println("Yearly interest rate: " + percent.format(interestRate));
                System.out.println("Number of years: " + years);
                System.out.println("Monthly payment: " + currency.format(monthlyPayment));

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Continue? (y/n): ");
                choice =sc.next();
                System.out.println();

            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: getDouble is coded as if it is a method, but there no such method defined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `getDouble` and `getInt` are string functions so you would have to get a string first then call those methods. However, since you have a scanner, I assume you want to use that with the `nextXXX` methods:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
double d = sc.nextDouble();
```

You can use this complete snippet for educational purposes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your double: ");
        double d = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your integer: ");
        int i = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You entered:  " + d + " and " + i);
    }
}
```

Transcript:

```
Enter your double: 3.14159
Enter your integer: 42
You entered:  3.14159 and 42
```

Basically, the process is:

- Instantiate a scanner, using the standard input stream.
- Use `print` for your prompts.
- Use the scanner `nextXXX` methods for getting the input values.

---

A little more assistance here, based on your comments.

In your main function, you have:

```
double loanAmount = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter loan amount: ", 0.0, 1000000.0)
```

and that function has the prototype:

```
public static double getDoubleWithinRange(
    Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max)
```

That means those variables in the prototype will be set to the values from the call. So, to prompt for the information, you could use something like (and this is to replace the `d = getDouble(sc, prompt);` line):

```
System.out.print(prompt);
double d = sc.nextDouble();
```

And there you have it, you've prompted the user and input the double from them. The first line prints out the prompt, the second uses the scanner to get the input from the user.

As an aside, your checks for the minimum and maximum are good but your error messages have hard-coded values of `0` and `100K`. I would suggest that you use the *parameters* to tailor these messages, such as changing:

```
System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater tha 0.0");
```

into:

```
System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min);
```

That way, if `min` or `max` change in future , your users won't get confused :-)

---

I'll leave it up to you to do a similar thing for the integer input. It *is* your homework, after all :-)

Comment: where do I place that code? Does it go instead of the getDouble? Thats what I really don't understand. i did another project last week and I was all over the place. I basically had things backwards which really screwed me up.

Comment: @Jeremy, I've updated the answer with a complete (though small) program which illustrates what you need to do. I won't do too much work for you since this is probably coursework and you'll feel better if you nut it out yourself with a _little_ help (and some might say, more importantly than feeling better, you'll _be_ better).

Comment: so are you saying I need to rewrite my main so it's more like what you have coded? How do I send to my validator?

Comment: No, you just need to fix the bits that accept info from the user. Where you call `getDouble`, you should be using the scanner, like in my code. Ditto for `getInt`.

Comment: But what about my main? Isn't that where I'm asking the user for input and then sending it to the getDouble section? Thank you by the way.

Comment: I'm still confused. If I'm understanding you correctly I'm supposed to write the "enter double" in my getdoublewithinrange method and getintwithinrange method correct? What happens to the part in my main where I am already including that? What about where I am declaring my minimum and maximum numbers?

Comment: Your main doesn't print that, it just passes it to getDoubleWithinRange so _it_ can print it. Hang on, I'll give you a little more to go on in the answer.

Comment: I understand what you are saying with it printing the message but I have used the getDoubleWithinRange to collect 2 sets of data the loan amount and the interest rate. I compared it to some code I found in the book I am using and assumed it would be the right path. It made sense as I typed it but because I'm learning I could be wrong.

Comment: @JeremyBorton, that's fine. What you've done there is _perfect._ The prompt is passed to the function where it can be printed. The two calls to that function pass two _different_ prompts (and min/max limits), one for amount, one for interest. By printing `prompt`, you'll get the right one. It's just the input bit that needs cleaning up within the functions. The using of min/max for the errors is vital since it's only 0/100K for the loan amount. If you enter an interest amount of 21%, the error message will currently say it need to be less than 100K.

Comment: I made the changes to both the getDoubleWithinRange and getIntWithinRange and it doesn't seem to print. Am I supposed to declare that prompt or I guess how does it know that's the prompt? Is it because of the order it's in? Also when I declared my int = i and double = d I initialized them to 0. Was that smart? These are just some more things I'm unclear on how they work.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made the implementation of your getDouble(Scanner,String) and getInt(Scanner,String) that's why you're getting the red line.

since you already have a scanner, and prompt string change it to this

```
System.out.print(prompt);
d = sc.nextDouble();
```

and for the integer

```
System.out.print(prompt);
i = sc.nextInt();
```